# phonegap-plugin-push in monaca not working when set SENDER_ID in plugin configuration

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, monaca

I am using Monaca to build my application phonegap, everything works fine, now I'm trying to import the plugin phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push. This plugin is an external plugin, then I have upgraded my account to developer plan, in the configuration of the plugin I have set the SENDER_ID like this SENDER_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXX.

the problem comes when I want to compile my app or a new custom debugger:

-Check AndroidManifest.xml is correct.

-Check KeyStore setting

the complete trace is as follows

```
Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/571550297e2193515015be16
Downloading project
Download complete
Running for 4.1
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/571550297e2193515015be16/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.splashscreen&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.camera&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.file&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.file-transfer&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;org.apache.cordova.geolocation&quot; for android
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Installing &quot;phonegap-plugin-push&quot; for android
cordova version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/571550297e2193515015be16/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
cordova-android version not detected (lacks script &quot;/private/tmp/monaca/571550297e2193515015be16/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version&quot; ), continuing.
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install &apos;phonegap-plugin-push&apos;:Error: Uh oh!
cannot find &quot;/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/com.android.support:support-v13:23+/project.properties&quot; referenced in &lt;framework&gt;
    at Object.AndroidProject.addSubProject (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/android-project.js:70:51)
    at module.exports.framework.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:110:27)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Error: Uh oh!
cannot find &quot;/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/com.android.support:support-v13:23+/project.properties&quot; referenced in &lt;framework&gt;
    at Object.AndroidProject.addSubProject (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/android-project.js:70:51)
    at module.exports.framework.install (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/android.js:110:27)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
Build error: Error building project source code
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.